# Steptimer.getTotalSeconds within steptimer.h returning 0, c++ visual studio 2013, directx app

Tags: c++, timer, directx

I'm trying to use the given code within steptimer.h to set up code that will run every two seconds. However with the code below, timer.GetTotalSeconds() always returns 0.

Unfortunately there isn't much information readily available on StepTimer.h (at least I believe due to a lack of useful search results), so I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light as to why the timer isn't recording the elapsed seconds. Am I using it incorrectly?

Code from Game.h, Game.cpp and StepTimer.h are included below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

From Game.cpp:

```
        double time = timer.GetTotalSeconds();
    if (time >= 2) {
        laser_power++;
        timer.ResetElapsedTime();
    }
```

Initialised in Game.h:

```
DX::StepTimer timer;
```

From Common/StepTimer.h:

```
    #pragma once

#include <wrl.h>

namespace DX
{
    // Helper class for animation and simulation timing.
    class StepTimer
    {
    public:
        StepTimer() :
            m_elapsedTicks(0),
            m_totalTicks(0),
            m_leftOverTicks(0),
            m_frameCount(0),
            m_framesPerSecond(0),
            m_framesThisSecond(0),
            m_qpcSecondCounter(0),
            m_isFixedTimeStep(false),
            m_targetElapsedTicks(TicksPerSecond / 60)
        {
            if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&m_qpcFrequency))
            {
                throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
            }

            if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_qpcLastTime))
            {
                throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
            }

            // Initialize max delta to 1/10 of a second.
            m_qpcMaxDelta = m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart / 10;
        }

        // Get elapsed time since the previous Update call.
        uint64 GetElapsedTicks() const                      { return m_elapsedTicks; }
        double GetElapsedSeconds() const                    { return TicksToSeconds(m_elapsedTicks); }

        // Get total time since the start of the program.
        uint64 GetTotalTicks() const                        { return m_totalTicks; }
        double GetTotalSeconds() const                      { return TicksToSeconds(m_totalTicks); }

        // Get total number of updates since start of the program.
        uint32 GetFrameCount() const                        { return m_frameCount; }

        // Get the current framerate.
        uint32 GetFramesPerSecond() const                   { return m_framesPerSecond; }

        // Set whether to use fixed or variable timestep mode.
        void SetFixedTimeStep(bool isFixedTimestep)         { m_isFixedTimeStep = isFixedTimestep; }

        // Set how often to call Update when in fixed timestep mode.
        void SetTargetElapsedTicks(uint64 targetElapsed)    { m_targetElapsedTicks = targetElapsed; }
        void SetTargetElapsedSeconds(double targetElapsed)  { m_targetElapsedTicks = SecondsToTicks(targetElapsed); }

        // Integer format represents time using 10,000,000 ticks per second.
        static const uint64 TicksPerSecond = 10000000;

        static double TicksToSeconds(uint64 ticks)          { return static_cast<double>(ticks) / TicksPerSecond; }
        static uint64 SecondsToTicks(double seconds)        { return static_cast<uint64>(seconds * TicksPerSecond); }

        // After an intentional timing discontinuity (for instance a blocking IO operation)
        // call this to avoid having the fixed timestep logic attempt a set of catch-up 
        // Update calls.

        void ResetElapsedTime()
        {
            if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_qpcLastTime))
            {
                throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
            }

            m_leftOverTicks = 0;
            m_framesPerSecond = 0;
            m_framesThisSecond = 0;
            m_qpcSecondCounter = 0;
        }

        // Update timer state, calling the specified Update function the appropriate number of times.
        template<typename TUpdate>
        void Tick(const TUpdate& update)
        {
            // Query the current time.
            LARGE_INTEGER currentTime;

            if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&currentTime))
            {
                throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
            }

            uint64 timeDelta = currentTime.QuadPart - m_qpcLastTime.QuadPart;

            m_qpcLastTime = currentTime;
            m_qpcSecondCounter += timeDelta;

            // Clamp excessively large time deltas (e.g. after paused in the debugger).
            if (timeDelta > m_qpcMaxDelta)
            {
                timeDelta = m_qpcMaxDelta;
            }

            // Convert QPC units into a canonical tick format. This cannot overflow due to the previous clamp.
            timeDelta *= TicksPerSecond;
            timeDelta /= m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart;

            uint32 lastFrameCount = m_frameCount;

            if (m_isFixedTimeStep)
            {
                // Fixed timestep update logic

                // If the app is running very close to the target elapsed time (within 1/4 of a millisecond) just clamp
                // the clock to exactly match the target value. This prevents tiny and irrelevant errors
                // from accumulating over time. Without this clamping, a game that requested a 60 fps
                // fixed update, running with vsync enabled on a 59.94 NTSC display, would eventually
                // accumulate enough tiny errors that it would drop a frame. It is better to just round 
                // small deviations down to zero to leave things running smoothly.

                if (abs(static_cast<int64>(timeDelta - m_targetElapsedTicks)) < TicksPerSecond / 4000)
                {
                    timeDelta = m_targetElapsedTicks;
                }

                m_leftOverTicks += timeDelta;

                while (m_leftOverTicks >= m_targetElapsedTicks)
                {
                    m_elapsedTicks = m_targetElapsedTicks;
                    m_totalTicks += m_targetElapsedTicks;
                    m_leftOverTicks -= m_targetElapsedTicks;
                    m_frameCount++;

                    update();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Variable timestep update logic.
                m_elapsedTicks = timeDelta;
                m_totalTicks += timeDelta;
                m_leftOverTicks = 0;
                m_frameCount++;

                update();
            }

            // Track the current framerate.
            if (m_frameCount != lastFrameCount)
            {
                m_framesThisSecond++;
            }

            if (m_qpcSecondCounter >= static_cast<uint64>(m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart))
            {
                m_framesPerSecond = m_framesThisSecond;
                m_framesThisSecond = 0;
                m_qpcSecondCounter %= m_qpcFrequency.QuadPart;
            }
        }

    private:
        // Source timing data uses QPC units.
        LARGE_INTEGER m_qpcFrequency;
        LARGE_INTEGER m_qpcLastTime;
        uint64 m_qpcMaxDelta;

        // Derived timing data uses a canonical tick format.
        uint64 m_elapsedTicks;
        uint64 m_totalTicks;
        uint64 m_leftOverTicks;

        // Members for tracking the framerate.
        uint32 m_frameCount;
        uint32 m_framesPerSecond;
        uint32 m_framesThisSecond;
        uint64 m_qpcSecondCounter;

        // Members for configuring fixed timestep mode.
        bool m_isFixedTimeStep;
        uint64 m_targetElapsedTicks;
    };
}
```

Comment: Alrighty got what I wanted with the code below. Was missing the .Tick(####) call.

    timer.Tick([&]() {
    
       double time = timer.GetTotalSeconds();
       
       if (time >= checkpt) {
        laser_power++;
        checkpt += 2;
       }
      });

Just fixed an integer checkpt to increment by 2 each time so that it runs every 2 seconds. There's probably a better way to do it, but it's 3.30am so I'm being lazy for the sake of putting my mind at ease.

Comment: p.s. would post as an answer, but sadly i can't answer my own posts within 8 hours due to my teenie current rep

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty got what I wanted with the code below. Was missing the .Tick(####) call.

```
timer.Tick([&]() {

            double time = timer.GetTotalSeconds();

            if (time >= checkpt) {
                laser_power++;
                checkpt += 2;
            }
        });
```

Just fixed an integer checkpt to increment by 2 each time so that it runs every 2 seconds. There's probably a better way to do it, but it's 3.30am so I'm being lazy for the sake of putting my mind at ease.